# Java Method return Types from Inheritance

Tags: java, oop, generics, inheritance

I'm writing a method in a class `Parent` that returns a set of some object `A`. However, I have a class `Child` (inheriting form `Parent`). I want it to return a set of some object `B` (`B` inheriting from `A`).

More specifically, my methods looks something like this (it throws compile errors right now).

`Parent` class method:

```
public abstract <T extends A> Set<T> getSet();
```

`Child` class (extends `Parent` class) method:

```
public <T extends B> Set<T> getSet() {...}
```

Is it possible to do this, or does it not make sense?

Comment: Type parameters have scopes. I think you should define both of your `Parent` and `Child` classes as inner classes. And then you can use a type parameter for class level to get what you want

Comment: @Jude could you explain what you mean define **both** as inner classes?

Comment: I did some formatting on your post. Note that in markdown you make a new section by leaving an empty line. You don't have to do `<br/>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, let me explain why your code does not compile. Basically, if you have `class A {}` and `class B extends A {}` then `Set<B>` is ***not*** a sub-type of `Set<A>`. So if your parent method returns a `Set<A>`, your override must return the same thing. A `Set<B>` is a *completely different type*.

Likewise, `Set<T extends B>` is not a sub-type of `Set<T extends A>`. The full explanation is found in [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html).

The closest solution that I can think of, uses wildcards:

```
class A {}

class B extends A {}

abstract class Parent {
    abstract Set<? extends A> getSet();
}

class Child extends Parent {
    Set<? extends B> getSet() {
        return new HashSet<B>();
    }
}
```

`Set<? extends B>` **is** a sub-type of `Set<? extends A>`, and this now works because of [covariant return types](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/covariant_return_types_in_java) (appreciate the comments from Lii & Marco13 below).

Depending on what you are trying to achieve exactly, this might be more limited than you expect, but is probably as close as it gets.

Perhaps something similar could be achieved using inner classes, as Jude said, but I don't see how that would be a more convenient solution.

Comment: This seems like a good solution to the problem, you are right that wild cards is the key here. But the solution contains some unnecessary elements: 1) You can remove the type parameters on the classes altogether. You actually never use them at all. 2) `Child.getSet` can be declared to return `Set<B>`, the wild cards are only necessary on the super class (unless you plan to make another class that extends `Child` and override the method one more.)

Comment: I actually do use the type parameter - I return a new HashSet of type T. Yes, I could remove type parameters (that was my initial solution), but then the actual type of the Set would have to be determined by the method. I.e. you'd need a new method for Set<C>, Set<D>, etc., even though the return type would be the same. My solution allows to achieve this behavior by creating new instances of the same class instead, just using a different type param. Pardon me if I misunderstood your point, however!

Comment: Okay, I then I understand your intention with the type parameter on the classes. But I don't think that is what the poster asks about. And I'm still confused about your use of `T`. Given only the code that you show, there is no point at all with the type parameter. You can change `new HashSet<T>()` to `new HashSet<B>()` (or to `new HashSet<>()`) and the code will compile and work in exactly the same way. Maybe you want `getSet` to return `Set<T>` or `Set<? extends T>` instead?

Comment: Agree, type param is surely not necessary on the `Parent` (already amended my answer). You are right that given only this code, it does not make a difference whether it's there on the `Child` either, since you can't really do much with the generic param. You could with some additional code, e.g. if you provided a way to instantiate T. Anyway, not entirely sure what the OP was trying to achieve either, which is why I did not want to give an answer in the first place... :]

Comment: The edited code does not compile, with the `<T extends B> extends Parent <B>` part. Again: The `<T extends B>` and the `<B>` can simply be omitted. The key is the wildcards, and the fact that `Set<? extends B>` indeed **is** a subtype of `Set<? extends A>` when `B extends A` (and this is exactly the covariance that Lii pointed out).

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to remove the <B>... Anyway, I've read the question again, and it seems that you are both right, I misinterpreted the question. I'll amend the answer to reflect all of this in a minute..